# Eclipse editor unable to display file contents

Tags: eclipse, editor

I've run into a very strange issue with my Eclipse installation. In fact, I've tried installing three different instances and the problem persists, so something must be seriously messed up with my machine.

The best way I can describe it is this. When I open a file in Eclipse (regardless of file type - I've tried .java, .js, .xml, etc.), the file appears to open and the filename is shown at the top of the editor panel as normal. But the file itself appears to be empty or blank.

Upon clicking in the editor window to attempt typing, it gets even more strange. The normal blinking black cursor is the full height of the window. Typing doesn't actually do anything. No text shows up, but it appears as if the file is being edited because the (*) symbol displays next to the filename as if it hasn't been saved since it was last changed.

I would provide a screenshot, but it's simply a blank window with a giant typing cursor. My current environment information is below, but like I said, I've had the issue with three different versions of Eclipse. Also, it's peculiar that this started happening seemingly randomly. Everything was fine but my machine was overdue for a restart. After restarting I opened up my workspace and this just sort of happened. I haven't been able to find any suggestions that aren't "reinstall" or "run Eclipse with the -clean tag" (neither of which worked).

Windows 7 Enterprise

Service Pack 1

Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2695 v2 @ 2.40GHz

RAM: 8GB

System type: 64-bit

Eclipse Mars 4.5.2

Comment: Are you able to select text in those editors? Check your Font and Color preferences.

Comment: @nitind Yeah that's not the issue. Just imagine looking at a blank file. There's no text to even select and typing doesn't even more the cursor.